# iOS storyboard container view's autosizing mask

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

On storyboard, I dragged a container view into a view. I am not using auto layouts. I want to size it so that this view gets expanded and shrink depending on whether it's a 3.5 inch or a 4 inch screen (it should tag to the bottom of the screen). However the autoresizing mask doesn't seem have an effect when I run it in the 3.5 inch or the 4 inch simulator -- it says the same size. What could I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're really not using Autolayout: open your storyboard, click on the File Inspector (which is the first panel to the right with the file icon), and make sure 'Use Autolayout is unchecked'.

Next select your Container View, go to the Size Inspector (which is the one with the ruler icon) and from the "Arrange" menu first select "Fill container vertically" and then "Fill container horizontally".

For me, this achieved the effect you wanted. I print out my  Container View's frame in viewDidLoad and it changes depending on whether I'm on a 3.5" or 4" iPhone.

Comment: I'm not using autolayout. But "Fill container vertically" simply fills the container view to the entire view of the parent controller. And that's not what I want. When I resize it back to the position it should be it doesn't tag to the bottom.

Comment: When I do "fill container vertically" and then I grab the top of the ContainerView and drag it down to let it fill less than the full screen, it still properly anchors to the bottom and gets resized when I change devices. I recommend removing your collection and re-adding it and make sure you're not programmatically setting the autoresize mask.